# Migrating Old Wordpress to New Wordpress Server, Themes and Media Not Loading

Tags: wordpress

I have followed the following steps in migration of godaddy to Cpanel and site loads, but none of my media or themes load.  I'm also not above to change theme or add new media.

1) zip old wp-content

2) export old SQL db

3) delete new wp-content,
   and replace with #1

4) delete old SQL db, and replace with #2

5) update site URL in wp_options table in new SQL db

6) clear cache and
   cookies and tried to load website again

I'm stuck here, and have tried many different ways of doing this, and each time exact same result where my page loads, but no media or themes.  thank you and looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP uses *absolute* links (including the URL) for all `href` and `src` attributes, and these are saved in the database.

So you not only have to update the site URL in the `wp_options` table, but ALL instances of the site URL in your whole database (i.e. in all tables) before importing it (i.e. the SQL file you exported) into the new site.

This can simply be done with the search/replace function in a regular text editor (replace all).

Comment: thanks for info.  But how would that explain not being about to add a new theme to the new site?

Comment: Well, ALL file relations are saved in the database. When you try to install or upload themes and media in the WP backend, WP also needs to know where to put them, and that also depends on those database entries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all update both "siteurl" and "home" in wp_options table.

Secondly, WordPress store attached media in an separate table by full path along domain name. 
You can update old domain name with new domain name through [search and replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/).

After activating the plugin on new host. Follow method in screenshot to replace all urls in database at once.
[image]

Cheers.